# include a phar file in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, phar

A company release its PHP SDK as a PHAR file. The sample file it gave is like:

```
include 'BaiduBce.phar';
require 'SampleConf.php';

use BaiduBce\BceClientConfigOptions;
use BaiduBce\Util\Time;
use BaiduBce\Util\MimeTypes;
use BaiduBce\Http\HttpHeaders;
```

I want to use it in a Symfony 2 project. So what is the best practice of including a vendor PHAR file in a SYmfony2 project?

Comment: Have you search for the analog lib on pavkagist?

Comment: Where do you download it? Usually a phar is a simple zipped standalone php library